# DataMapper Time property converting to DateTime in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, datamapper

Im using DataMapper as the ORM in my Rails application. I have defined a property of Time datatype as follows

```
property :arrival_time, Time, :required => true
```

DataMapper is storing it as DateTime in MySQL database, so what gets stored is like for example,2012-06-28 14:17:00. I would like to store only the time part in the column, example 14:17:00. Can this be done ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

while creating table use

```
  t.time :arrival_time
```